# IBU Biathlon theme

Tags: media, biathlon

I was wondering who wrote the IBU (International Biathlon Union) theme and whether it is part of a longer song or not. The theme can be found at the first and second file [here](http://mp3hamster.net/search/biathlon).

I have no clue whether the text above it (about a Swedish band named Tribulation) has anything to do with the theme song. Although I do like rock music, I felt little for listening to the entire repertoire of a death metal band...

Comment: A little late, but you might give this question a try at [musicfans.se]. Maybe they know?